# Change value of an IF condition found in IDA

Tags: ida, assembly, ollydbg, decompilation, executable

so I have the .idb file of an executeable I want to modify.

In the IDB file, I found this code

[image]

And I basically want to change 4111006 to 1006 in that IF condition.
however, when I press TAB to go to pseudocode, this is what it shows me

[image]

(marked in yellow)

So it shows 4121000 and 4111001 in these segments, but it doesn't show the rest and the one I want to change (4111006), preventing me from finding it in ollydbg / a hex editor and changing it.

Is it possible to find 4111006 and change it to a different integer value? If so, how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: First you need to learn assemble language and understand how the decompiled code corresponds to the disassembly.

Comment: please do not post code as images. It's really hard to copy paste from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how those IFs are constructed in the assembly is a bit different than what you see in high-level overview in IDA code.

Apart from the first one, ifs are represented with subtraction (`sub` & `dec`) and `jz`.

This code is an alternative of conditions:

```
if (Args == 4121000 || Args == 4111001)
    goto LABEL_297
```

and is represented in asm with this code:

```
6DCC53: mov ecx, 4121000
6DCC55: cmp eax, ecx
6DCC57: jg short loc_6DCC93
6DCC5D: jz loc_6DCBB6
6DCC62: sub eax, 4111001
6DCC68: jz loc_6DCBB6
```

because in the first 4 lines (excluding 3rd) you have the first part of the if (standard `cmp` + `jz`) and then later a value of `4111001` is subtracted from `eax`. If it results in zero then we know that the value was equal to it and we jump to the same location. So IDA identifies this as an alternative of two values: `4121000`, `4111001`.

The following ifs are represented with this:

```
dec eax
jz loc_6DCXXX
```

Remember that after the line `6DCC62` the value in `eax` we compare with is already `-4111001`, so if we subtract one more time and if we get zero, we know that the initial value was `4111002`. This is why IDA represents this as:

```
if (Args == 4111002)
    goto LABEL_346
```

The next branches are the same. So you if want to modify the last one, you would have to modify the line that IDA correctly pointed you to + the one before. So instead of having there the same pattern as for all the other ifs, you need to write:

```
cmp ecx, 1006
jz 6DCD28
```

and assemble such opcodes.